# Repurposed PHP/MySQL CRUD code that used to work no longer works

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I'm an occasional PHP/MySQL hobbyist, meaning every couple of years I get an idea for a simple CRUD project and try to execute it. This last happened in Oct 2018. Yesterday I started another CRUD project, hoping to repurpose some old code. But my INSERT commands are not working. The code is literally taken from an old live site I had that worked perfectly.

I've spent an entire day googling and there's a lot of old stuff out there. I did the usual, turning on PHP errors and echoing out my variables (which turn up empty). I know I'm connecting to my database because I echoed out a success message. Not really looking for anyone to solve my problem for me, but rather to tell me, yeah things have change and you need to check out X source.

Here's a stripped down version of my code. Has PHP/MySQL CRUD syntax changed since 2018?

```
    // Connect to database
    require_once "mysqli-connect.php";
    $mysqli = dbConnect('dbname');

    // Define variables and initialize with empty values
    $fname = $lname = "";

    // Process the form
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        // Set first name
        $fname = trim($_POST['fname']);

        // Set last name
        $lname = trim($_POST['lname']);

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $query = "INSERT INTO test_table (fname, lname) VALUES (?, ?)";

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $param_fname, $param_lname);

            // Set parameters
            $param_fname = $fname;
            $param_lname = $lname;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){

                // Get last inserted id
                $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);

                // Redirect to photo upload page

            ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.location = 'upload_image.php'; // This does NOT redirect like it should
                </script>

            <?php
                exit;
            } // End execute

        } // End prepare

        // Close statement
        $stmt->close();

    } // End process form

    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close(); 

?>

            <form class="needs-validation" novalidate action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">

                    <label for="fname">*First name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>" maxlength="20" autofocus required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Valid first name is required.
                    </div>

                    <label for="lname">*Last name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lname" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>" maxlength="20" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Valid last name is required.
                    </div>

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-submit btn-block" value="Continue">
            </form>
```

Comment: Something that's odd is that `$param_fname` and `$param_lname` are set after the bind that uses them. Is that intentional? Also, have you tried [reading the MySQL errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php).?

Comment: which variables echo empty? Does the prepare stage get passed correctly? Is the stmt executed? The table exists `SHOW CREATE TABLE test_table`?

Comment: I thought that was weird, too, but that's the syntax I learned. I just posted my own answer below. I had to add name="submit" to the submit button. It was literally that simple. It works perfectly, so that bind syntax, weird as it looks, works.

Answer (score 0):

I literally pasted "$_POST['submit']" in a google search and the first result said

> isset( $_POST['submit'] ) : This line checks if the form is submitted using the isset() function, but works only if the form input type submit has a name attribute (name="submit")

All it took to fix this was adding name="submit" to my input type. I didn't have that in the original file from 2018. Weird.

EDIT: This worked in my test table, but not my real table. Turns out MySQL doesn't like table names with underscores. While they are perfectly valid characters, apparently there's no guarantee they'll always work. Once I removed the underscores, everything worked fine. Took a long time just adding, removing and changing things one at a time.

Comment: That would be a pretty serious bug.